# Format integer to 2 places

Tags: iphone, integer

I'm trying to format integer to 2 characters, i.e. 01, 02, 03 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4.

I've done a few google searches but could not find anything. Can @"%d" be changed to reflect 2 characters ?

```
timeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
  NSString *timeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
  [timeArray addObject:timeValue];
  NSLog(@"Time: %@", timeValue);
 }
```

Regards,
Stephen

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got it !!!!

@"%02d"